# Why doesn't the API return a 'locked date' for this locked answer?

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, answers, posts, locked-posts

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31932/295232) has been locked, yet when I [ask the API about this post](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=31932&filter=!)Q29mbLxf6w2ArlRSR4Kv3ra&site=meta&run=true) it fails to return a `locked_date`:

[image]

It's a rather old lock, but I can't see anything suspicious in the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/31932/timeline) or the [Post History](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/968747).

Comment: PS:  What error(s) does the API give when your script tries to write/edit a locked answer?

Comment: "Account is not allowed to suggest edits", see the bug report [Wrong error message when attempting to edit a locked answer](https://stackapps.com/q/8520/34061)

Answer (score 1):

Does it work on answers at all?

- Here's [a newer locked answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289498/148310).   Yet, it [doesn't have a `locked_date`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=289498&filter=!)Q29mbLxf6w2ArlRSR4Kv3ra&site=meta&run=true) either.
- It's [not a filter issue](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=289498&filter=default&site=meta&run=true).
- Nor is it fixed [in version 2.3](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/answers/289498?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta&filter=!)Q29mbLxf6w2ArlRSR4Kv3ra) (yet).

#### Also, additional [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

The [`post` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/post) should also return a `locked_date`.

---

A [sample locked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/148310) does [return a `locked_date` as expected](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=17204&filter=!iCF4LoRm4Rfs1Jb)Wf0fU)&site=meta&run=true).

Comment: Good point(s). I assumed it was fixed because of the [status-completed] tag on the related feature request. And yes, I've encountered situations where a `locked_date` on the Post type would've saved me another API call.

Comment: Alas, that feature request was several hamster lifetimes ago, on a different API architecture.  ("Regression testing?!  We don't need no stinking...")

Comment: Something like 'This account is not allowed to suggest edits' even though I have 2k rep.