# Wrong error message when attempting to edit a locked answer

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, editing, locked-posts

When attempting to edit a locked answer like [this one](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3333) via the [`/answers/{id}/edit` API method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-answer), I get an error message:

> Account is not allowed to suggest edits

I have [the privilege to edit the post](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), so I'm not actually suggesting an edit. Since the API [does not always determine the locked state correctly](https://stackapps.com/q/8205/34061), I can't check upfront if I'm able to edit the post.